# Replacing [TD] with <TD> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I have a return data string from an Oracle process that outputs `[TD]` and `[/TD]` rather than `<TD>` and `</TD>` to denote an html table cell. I need to translate  `[TD]` to `<TD>` and `[/TD]` to `<TD>` in an element with an ID of unchangedValues using Javascript.

I've Googled and searched on here and this is the closest I've got so far, neither of which work. Any help here would be most gratefully received.

```
function strReplace() {
    var string = document.getElementById('unchangedValues').innerHTML;
    var res1 = string.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
  if (p1) return "<";
  if (p2) return ">"
});
}
```

and I've also tried:

```
function substituteValues() {

  const str = document.getElementById('unchangedValues').innerHTML;
  const res1 = str.replace(/\[TD\]/g, '\<TD\>');

  document.getElementById('unchangedValues').innerHTML = res1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `.replace(/\[(\/?TD)]/g, '<$1>')`

Comment: Seems like a basic duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @isherwood Could be, but OP is using `g`.

Comment: Does anything work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```js
console.log(
   "[TD] and [/TD]".replace(/\[(\/?TD)]/gi, '<$1>')
)
```

The `/\[(\/?TD)]/gi` regex matches

- `\[`  - a `[`
- `(\/?TD)` - Group 1: `/` 1 or 0 times and then `TD`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `/gi` - multiple occurrences, case insensitive.

If there may be attributes in `TD` use

```js
// Assuming values can't contain ] and " are value qualifiers
console.log( '[TD key="value"] and [/TD]'.replace(/\[(\/?TD(?:\s[^\]]*)?)]/gi, '<$1>') );
// Assuming values can contain ] and " or ' are value qualifiers
console.log( '[TD key="va[l]ue here" key2=\'value 2\' auto ] and [/TD]'.replace(/\[(\/?TD(?:\s+\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\w+))?)*)\s*]/gi, '<$1>') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution for any tag, not just `[TD]`:

```js
console.log(
  'Lorem [TD FOO="ipsum"] dolor sit [/TD] amet'
  .replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, '<$1>')
);
```

Comment: Why the regexes at all?

Comment: @isherwood Because that is how you may replace all occurrences

Comment: True but the question doesn't mention it can be `[td]`

Comment: In this case the response will always be [TD] but a case sensitive answer would be good also.

Comment: This is great guys, thanks. I'll get to trying these answers out over the next few hours and feedback then. Great stuff, thanks!

Comment: @enCue You might keep getting new answers faster than you can try them

Answer (score 0):

How about that with 2 `str.replace()` only for brackets?

```js
var str = 'John [TD] Smith [/TD]';
var newstr = str.replace(/\[/gi, '<').replace(/]/gi,'>');
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is on a `table` element or even a `tr` element, and the format is not correct (I don't know since you didn't post the HTML), the browser will move the invalid stuff outside of the table (or closest valid location). You can see that when run, there is no data within the `tr` and this is making your code  attempt to format an empty string then save the empty string back.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('unchangedValues').innerHTML)
```

```html
<table id="unchangedValues">
  <tr>
    [TD]Hi[/TD]
    [TD]Hi[/TD]
    [TD]Hi[/TD]
    [TD]Hi[/TD]
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see by the output, the `[TD]` and `[/TD]`'s are all gone from the table, however if you inspect the output, the values will have been moved above or below the table automatically by the browser.

To fix the issue, you need have the items within memory. You can then modify the items and then save them into the table.

```js
let str = `[TD]Hi[/TD] 
    [TD]Hi[/TD] 
    [TD]Hi[/TD] 
    [TD]Hi[/TD]`
    
document.querySelector('#unchangedValues tr').innerHTML = str.replace(/\[(\/?TD)\]/g, '<$1>')
```

```html
<table id="unchangedValues">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also check an replace with the regExp of [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

```
if(str.indexOf('[TD]')!==-1 || str.indexOf('[/TD]')!==-1){str = str.replace(/\[(\/?TD)]/gi, '<$1>')}
```